# Solving time evolution equations in Hamiltonian formalism

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, time-evolution

I have 4 time evolution equations and the Hamiltonian $H(X_{1},X_{2},P_{1},P_{2})$ that generates the time evolution depends on 4 canonical coordinates but I would like to solve the differential equations(time evolution equations) but I cant be sure if the canonical coordinates depend on time or not. Here is the first evolution equation;

$$\frac{d X_{1}}{d t}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial P_{1}}=X_{2}=v$$

What I am missing is whether $X_{2}$ depends on time or not because if it does I can not solve the differential equation $\frac{d X_{1}}{d t}$. If opposite it's trivial to solve.

Thank you.

Comment: You should solve a _system_ of four equations, not only the equation for $X_1$. There is equation $dX_2/dt = \dots$ and $X_2$ almost surely depends on $t$.

Comment: Well if $\mathrm dX_2/\mathrm dt\neq0$, would it depend on time or no?

Comment: dX_2/dt is nonzero so it depends on time, actually they are Ostrogradsky's choices for the time evolution equations but then I do not know how to solve the differential equations because each one of them depends on other canonical coordinates and time.

Comment: Well you may have to do it numerically...

Comment: If your equations are linear with constant coefficients, then there are known standard methods how to solve systems of such equations.

Comment: Yes I also tried to solve it that way but there are 4 eigenvalues and 2 of them does not exist because they are not defined as the epsilon deviation from harmonic oscillator goes to zero.

Comment: What is the explicit formula for $H$?

Comment: H=(P_1)(X_1)+(P_2)(A)-L where A(X_1, X_2, P_2) and  L(X_1,X_2, A(X_1, X_2, P_2)). I denoted acceleration as A and Lagrangian as L.

Comment: $X_2$ depends implicitly on time.

Comment: Yes but if one tries to solve dX_1/dt=X_2(t) differential equation, how can one get a solution for X_1? Because we have no idea how X_2 looks like.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I figured out a way to solve the problem. I needed to linearize the equations first then rest was trivial to solve.